# Rock Paper Scissors programme

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop, do-while

I have been frustrated with this code. The goal is to create a rock paper scissors game, best of 3. I have tried to make a "while" loop but I've got it all wrong and ended up scrapping it back to what I started with, a non-looping code.

If anyone can enlighten me how to make it loop until the computer or player gets a score of 3 wins, I would be so grateful!! Thank you so much
Sorry I should clarify, it needs to loop until the user or computer has 3 wins, so they rebattle until the user or computer reaches 3 wins

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
    
public class RockPaperScissors
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner key;
    Random randGen;
    char userChoice, computerChoice;
    int winner, compInt;

    int computerScore;
    int userScore;
    int scoreCounter;

    /***** INITIALIZATION SECTION *****/
    key = new Scanner(System.in);
    randGen = new Random();
    userChoice = ' ';
    computerChoice = ' ';
    //winner = -1;
    compInt = -1;
    computerScore = 0;
    userScore = 0;
    scoreCounter = 0;

    System.out.println("What is your name?");
    String name = key.nextLine();
    System.out.println(name + " play rock, paper, or scissors with me!!");

    /***** INPUT SECTION *****/
    System.out.println("Please enter R for rock, P for paper, or S for scissors:");
    userChoice = key.next().toUpperCase().charAt(0);

    //key.close();

    /***** PROCESSING SECTION *****/
    compInt=randGen.nextInt(3);
    if (compInt == 0)
    {
        computerChoice = 'R';
    }
    else if (compInt == 1)
    {
        computerChoice = 'P';
    }
    else if (compInt == 2)
    {
        computerChoice = 'S';
    }
    
    winner = RockPaperScissors.decideWinner(userChoice,computerChoice);

    /***** OUTPUT SECTION *****/
    System.out.printf("Player: %c%nComputer: %c%n", userChoice, computerChoice);

   switch (winner)
    {
        case 0:
            System.out.println("It's a tie!");
            System.out.println(name + ": " + userScore + ", Computer:" + computerScore );
            break;

        case 1:
            System.out.println("You won!");
            userScore++;
            System.out.println(name + ": " + userScore + ", Computer:" + computerScore );
            break;

        case 2:
            System.out.println("Computer won!");
            computerScore++;
            System.out.println(name + ": " + userScore + ", Computer:" + computerScore );
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid choice, try again.");
            break;
    }
    //System.out.println("Thanks for playing!);
}

/***** STATIC METHODS *****/
/**Description: given two characters (R,P, or S) determines winner using rock
 * paper rules. Assume input is valid and error checking is done in main
 * programme. **/

public static int decideWinner(char p1,char p2)
{
    String combo;
    combo = String.format("%c%c", p1, p2);

    switch(combo)
    {
        case "RS":
        case "PR":
        case "SP":
            return 1;

        case "RP":
        case "PS":
        case "SR":
            return 2;

        case "RR":
        case "PP":
        case "SS":
            return 0;

    }
    return -1;
}

}
/***************************************************
 while(userScore == 3)
        {
            System.out.println("You won the game" +name+ "! Congratulations");
            scoreCounter++;
        }
        while(computerScore == 3)
        {
            System.out.println("Sorry " +name+ ", Computer won...");
            scoreCounter++;
        }
 **************************************************/
```

Comment: I'm thinking if you wanted to use a while loop you simply have to keep track of how many wins each have then *while ( (playerWins + computerWins) < 3) {//code}*.

Comment: @OmarAbdelBari if it's best of 3, he only has to keep track of how many rounds have been played. So simply: `while (rounds < 3) {//code}`.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. If my answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted :)

Comment: @M0e that's not exactly correct, if a round is a tie it does not count towards meeting the condition. Best 2 out of 3 means 2 wins. What happens if there are 1 or 3 ties, who wins?

Comment: But that also raises another point, if one player gets 2 wins then it can technically be over in 2 non-tie rounds. So I guess even more accurate is **while (playerWins < 2 && computerWins < 2)**

Comment: @OmarAbdelBari No, best out of 3 means best out of 3 *rounds*. Ties are therefore possible. https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Best+of+Three

Comment: @M0e using the same link given **the person or team who wins the majority of an odd number of games**. That is vague and doesn't really backup either of our points. I found another definition on merriam (which I feel doesn't defend either of our points) as well however it does have examples that do backup my case. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/best%20of%20three . In other words you don't have to play 3 rounds you just need  >50% of 3 wins to advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try splitting your code in methods that each have their own task, that way u can more easily lay out and control the behaviour of your program. E.g. in the case of user input, you can recursively call the method in case of invalid input.
For the while loop, I simply added a counter that increases after every game, until 3.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
    
public class RockPaperScissors
{

    private static int totalGames = 0;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner key;
    Random randGen;
    char userChoice, computerChoice;
    int winner;

    int computerScore;
    int userScore;

    /***** INITIALIZATION SECTION *****/
    key = new Scanner(System.in);
    randGen = new Random();
    computerChoice = ' ';
    //winner = -1;
    computerScore = 0;
    userScore = 0;

    System.out.println("What is your name?");
    String name = key.nextLine();
    System.out.println(name + " play rock, paper, or scissors with me!!");


    while(totalGames < 3) {
        userChoice = getUserChoice(key, false);

        /* PROCESSING SECTION */
        computerChoice = getComputerChoice(computerChoice, randGen.nextInt(3));

        winner = RockPaperScissors.decideWinner(userChoice, computerChoice);

        totalGames++;

        /* OUTPUT SECTION */
        System.out.printf("Player: %c%nComputer: %c%n", userChoice, computerChoice);

        switch (winner) {
            case 0:
                System.out.println("It's a tie!");
                System.out.println(name + ": " + userScore + ", Computer:" + computerScore);
                break;

            case 1:
                System.out.println("You won!");
                userScore++;
                System.out.println(name + ": " + userScore + ", Computer:" + computerScore);
                break;

            case 2:
                System.out.println("Computer won!");
                computerScore++;
                System.out.println(name + ": " + userScore + ", Computer:" + computerScore);
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid choice, try again.");
                break;
        }
    }
    //System.out.println("Thanks for playing!);
}

    private static char getComputerChoice(char computerChoice, int compInt) {
        if (compInt == 0)
        {
            computerChoice = 'R';
        }
        else if (compInt == 1)
        {
            computerChoice = 'P';
        }
        else if (compInt == 2)
        {
            computerChoice = 'S';
        }
        return computerChoice;
    }

    private static char getUserChoice(Scanner key, boolean retry) {
        char userChoice;
        /* INPUT SECTION */
        if(retry)
            System.out.println("You entered an invalid input, please try again...");
        System.out.println("Please enter R for rock, P for paper, or S for scissors:");
        try {
            userChoice = key.next().toUpperCase().charAt(0);
            if(userChoice != 'R' && userChoice != 'P' && userChoice != 'S')
                return getUserChoice(key, true);
        } catch (Exception e){
            return getUserChoice(key, true);
        }
        return userChoice;
    }

/***** STATIC METHODS *****/
/**Description: given two characters (R,P, or S) determines winner using rock
 * paper rules. Assume input is valid and error checking is done in main
 * programme. **/

public static int decideWinner(char p1,char p2)
{
    String combo;
    combo = String.format("%c%c", p1, p2);

    switch(combo)
    {
        case "RS":
        case "PR":
        case "SP":
            return 1;

        case "RP":
        case "PS":
        case "SR":
            return 2;

        case "RR":
        case "PP":
        case "SS":
            return 0;

    }
    return -1;
}

}
/***************************************************
 while(userScore == 3)
        {
            System.out.println("You won the game" +name+ "! Congratulations");
            scoreCounter++;
        }
        while(computerScore == 3)
        {
            System.out.println("Sorry " +name+ ", Computer won...");
            scoreCounter++;
        }
 **************************************************/
```